# Output database row in JavaScript loop

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops, var

I want to make a slideshow of data from database. I use php to print out the rows, then I placed that in  a html code, then I want to use javascript to loop the code using the `setInterval()` loop.

My question is: how can I output the rows and  use javascript to display that? because what I tried to do didn't work. I'm not experienced with javascript, and I tried to look up and try out different methods but it doesn't work for some reason.

This is what I tried to do last, but it does not print anything on page.

```
      ...
      $sel_query = "SELECT * FROM `classifieds` WHERE `title` !=''";
      $results = mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
      $results = mysqli_query($conn,$sel_query);
    
    
       
    
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {


       
     ?>
      

      ...
<body>


<div id="div"> </div>



<script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(displayCode, 1000);


    var codeBlock = '<div id="slider-frame" class="slider-frame">' +
                '<div class="slide-images">' +
                '<div class="img-container">' +
                '<h1>' + '<?php echo $row['title']; ?>' + '</h1>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<p>' + '<?php echo $row['description']; ?>' + '</p>' +
            '</div> </div>';


   function displayCode() {
      document.getElementById("div").innerHTML += codeBlock;
   }


</script>

<?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this your real code? `<body>` should be outside the loop at minimum. An `id` also must be unique, this would produce numerous elements with same `id`s.

Comment: You should create a REST api in PHP and return the result of the query as json. Then in the client you make an ajax call to retrieve the json, and render it at the client.

Comment: @user3783243 No this is not how my code exactly look. I just wanted to show only the important parts.

Comment: Is `<div id="slider-frame"` inside a loop?

Comment: @user3783243 It should be in the php  `while` loop, but idk if that actually works. Could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, an `id` should be unique. If JS or CSS is trying to target a specific one it will fail. So that might be your issue, if you can provide more details of `didn't work` that also could help.

Comment: @user3783243 I did change it, it might have fixed something but not the problem I'm having. But I appreciate the help anyways, so thank you! The problem I'm still having tho is with my javascript code. I'm trying to set a `function`  that print out data from database that I brought with php. I hope that this is not confusing. But it's not doing that. I understand that php and js are not exactly compatible, but I thought I'll give some methods a try.

Comment: You just need to remember PHP runs first. So long as you aren't expecting JS to run a `<?php` block you should be fine. If you are trying to do that you'd need to use ajax. I'm not clear what your issue is currently still unfortunately. Is the code rendering correctly but not executing as it should? Could you provide more context of what isn't working (with code and description)?\

Comment: @user3783243 My problem was that the `<?php  echo $row['title'] ?>` in my javascript code, did not work. It did not echo the row I wanted. I figured that this was happening because of the `+` in the var `codeBlock`. After deleting them and making the var one string it worked.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that the  in my javascript code, did not work. It did not echo the row I wanted. I figured that this was happening because of the + in the var codeBlock. After deleting them and making the var one string it worked.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    setInterval(displayCode, 1000);



   function displayCode() {
      document.getElementById("sliderFrame").innerHTML += '<div id="sliderFrame" class="slider-frame"> <div class="slide-images"> <div class="img-container">  <h1> <?php echo $row['title']; ?>  </h1> </div> <p> <?php echo $row['description']; ?> </p> </div> </div> ';

   }



    </script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).